# how to get records recursevly from multiple starting points?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is follow up to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594155/how-to-get-all-children-of-a-parent-row

This query gives all records who are children of X:

```
with recursive tree as (
   select  stocklocationid, parentid
   from tableA
   where stocklocationid = X
   union all
   select child.tableAid, child.parentid
   from tableA child
     join tree parent on parent.tableAid= child.parentid
)
select *
from tree;
```

This works... However it can only handle one starting point X.

I want to run it with muliple stating point...

I have a list: `{12,5,17,18}` , In my query i need to replace each number with X.  How do I make it so that It will do it automaticly and eleminate duplicates if any.

I want a single list that contains 12,5,17,18 and all thier desendences....

Comment: `where stocklocationid in (12,5,17,18)`